GraphQL not working when deployed on Heroku but working correctly on local (Shopify ruby gem)
I use a ruby app with the shopify gem (version 9.0.2)
Everything worked well, until recently, when suddenly it can't parse my GraphQL call on Heroku
But when I am doing the same process locally, it works
For example, on both :
-I am initializing the ShopifyAPI with the credentials, the api_version
-I do the following request
query_variables = {'gid' => gid}
    query_str = <<-'GRAPHQL'
      query($gid: ID!) {
        product(id: $gid) {
          id
        }
      }
    GRAPHQL

-After that I initialize the client :
client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.client

And then I try to parse
query_graph_ql = client.parse(query_str)

Locally it works well, but on Heroku I have the following error
"NoMethodError (undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass)"
and before a couple of months, it worked well on Heroku as well
It seems to come from GraphQL itself, but i don't understand why this error appeared
As if it wasn't correctly initialize on Heroku
It seems it's not link to my shop, since I tried on other where i didn't make any changes and it still does not work
Any idea from where the error come from ?
I tried : Making a Shopify GraphQL call on Heroku
Expected : receiving my data
Resulted : GraphQL Error : NoMethodError (undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass)
Edit: I have no problem with the REST API
Edit2 : The Backtrace in rails console (with heroku run rails c) :
app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/graphql-client-0.19.0/lib/graphql/client/document_types.rb:62:in `rescue in analyze_types'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/graphql-client-0.19.0/lib/graphql/client/document_types.rb:45:in `analyze_types'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/graphql-client-0.19.0/lib/graphql/client.rb:189:in `parse'
/app/lib/utilities/graphql.rb:29:in `query_shopify'
/app/lib/utilities/graphql.rb:368:in `get_product_by_id'
(irb):4:in `irb_binding'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/workspace.rb:85:in `eval'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/workspace.rb:85:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/context.rb:385:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:493:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:647:in `signal_status'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:490:in `block in eval_input'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:246:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `loop'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `each_top_level_statement'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:489:in `eval_input'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:428:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:427:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:427:in `run'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb.rb:383:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:64:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:96:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'


The gem version you are using is more than 4 years old. Several newer major versions have been released since then. Did you consider updating the shopify gem to a more recent version?

@spickermann Yes, I wanted to update to the new version, but my app is pretty big and there are a lot of changes to do for it to simply work again. I started doing it but I don't have the time for now (I will resume my work on it when I can)
From the error it really looks like it's more on the GraphQL side/initialization, If it was the gem itself, I would assume the REST API wouldn't work either (and it wouldn't work locally ?)

Can you provide the full stacktrace for the error?

@engineersmnky i edited my post by adding the backtrace from rails console
When i look into my gems location locally, i don't see the "graphql-client-0.19.0" folder, only the "graphql-client-0.18.0"

Sounds like you may have discovered your issue, you are using different versions (released almost 2 years apart).

@engineersmnky Oh, if I understand correctly, I have to force my gemfile to use the 0.18 version ? So that this one will be use on heroku ?
I don't have the gem gem 'graphql-client' in my Gemfile, i only have this (concerning my problem) :
gem 'shopify_api', '~> 9.0.2' gem 'graphql', '1.10.3'
And I didn't change their version recently (I know I need to be updated)
I suppose it shouldn't work locally either ? Maybe there is something I am not understanding

Try adding gem 'graphql-client', '0.18.0' to your Gemfile and see if that resolves the issue. The shopify-api simply requires graphql-client without a version specification.   Obviously upgrading shopify in the future is your best best and you should be able to remove this line at that time.

@engineersmnky Thanks! I will try this as soon as I can

The error was due to an update of the graphql-client gem
This gem has been updated this year, the version before was from 2022
The shopify gem version I use (9.0.2), use the last version of graphql-client and it's incompatible with this version of the shopify gem
I forced the previous version in my Gemfile and now it is working again
Thanks engineersmnky for the help
